# Why is "Create" disabled in Google Compute Engine VM instances?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Using the Google Developer Console "Compute Engine" I am trying to create a VM instance.  It seems I have filled out all the required fields.  I have referenced multiple tutorials and posts, and gone through every step. I cannot, however, select "Create"! The button is disabled.

In case it matters, I signed up for a free trial and associated that billing account with the project.  Previously, another project owner had done the same, but we never used any of his credits within the 60 day limit. Are the billing details perhaps the problem?

Comment: I wish people would post why they are casting down votes!  What is possibly the matter with this question?  It's a legitimate problem, stated clearly, and Google directs developers here to find Compute Engine solutions (so a miscategorization / wrong forum down vote is not called for).

Comment: I have similar issue. So I vote you up.

Comment: Much appreciated @davidt!  I don't understand down votes on questions 90% of the time.  SO is supposed to not be about opinions so much.  That's for Programmer Overflow.  An up/down on an answer should mean a solution worked for you or didn't, or is the "best" among multiple choices.  On a question, an up vote should mean "I had the same question", or "this is a good one".  A down vote on a question should be cast for a specific reason, and a comment should be left explaining it.  Like, "this is the wrong forum", or the question is not at all understandable, or clearly inaccurate/fictitious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was there was not a "network" selected for the VM.

Open the network section for the VM you are trying to create (you have to show the extended details).  According to Google's tech support - the network field should either not appear at all or should be set to "default".  For me, it appeared but had no option to select.

Of note, at this point I also created and associated a static ip in this network section per the directions I found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gce-discussion/create$20vm/gce-discussion/WTZci6X0s-c/RRtyXT14XW0J

When I discovered that no network could be set for the VM, I manually created one.  To do that, open the "Networking" page (which is outside of the Compute Engine, and found in the main menu of the developer's console). Then, go the "networks" section within that.  Click the "Create network" button.  If you have created a static ip like I did, it will then become associated with the new network.

If you go back into the Compute Engine, the "Create VM" button will now be available. That network drop down should indeed have disappeared.  I guess because there now is one - and only one.

-UPDATE-

After I got passed this issue, I was immediately presented with a new one which was directly related.  I couldn't connect via SSH.  It turned out to be the result of this manually added / selected network.  Here's my question and solution for that problem:
[Why can't I connect to a Google VM instance via SSH over a network other than "default"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33532933/why-cant-i-connect-to-a-google-vm-instance-via-ssh-over-a-network-other-than-d/33533326#33533326)